# Wordpress: How to insert javascript code (without referencing an external asset) using the API?

Tags: wordpress

Using `wp_enqueue_script()` I can add references to extenal .js assets, but I want to insert the actual javascript code inside `<script>` tags.

My limitation is that I can't add it directly to, for example, the `head.php` file because it's a user-configurable bit of javascript, so I want to read it from the theme options and insert it programmatically.

Is it possible to do this using the API?

Comment: Yes it's possible, but we need a little more information. Are you saying you want to add a field to the backend that allows users to paste whatever JS they want?  Or do you have an existing script you want to allow them to modify (e.g. by changing specific variables or options)?  Do you already know how to add UI elements to the admin panel or do you need help with that too?  Have you bothered looking through the WordPress Codex, specifically at the Options API reference?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Ennui thanks for your comment. It's the first thing you said: adding whatever JS the user pastes into a theme option. I have all the rest handled so far (using the Options API - with a page with options specific to the theme). Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `head` `hook` and then just `echo` out the `JS` as a `string` using `PHP`, like so;

```
<?php 
    function addUserScript() {
    $userScript = '<script>';
    $userScript .= YOURUSERSCRIPT;// get user script info
    $userScript .= '</script>';

    echo $userScript;
}
add_action('wp_head', 'addUserScript');
?>
```

Comment: @frntk Do note that this is incredibly dangerous since you're allowing the user to run any JS they want on your site... I sure hope you trust whomever you are giving this access to!

Comment: @Ennui, yeah I'm aware of the potential problems, but this is for a theme that will be sold to users and they will be appropriately warned about the dangers. Thanks!